# Medrash on Dovid Hamelech riding a Re'eim

Tags: sources-mekorot, animals, midrash, king-david, story-identification

I'm looking for a certain medrash. It's about Dovid Hamelech climbing up what he thinks is a mountain, but it actually ends up being a re'eim.

Comment: Where did you hear of this? Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is found in Midrash Tehillim (22:28):

> הושיעני מפי אריה ומקרני (ראמים) [רמים] עניתני. אמר ר' הונא בר אידי בשעה שהיה דוד רועה את הצאן, הלך ומצא את הראם ישן במדבר, והיה סבור בו שהוא הר ועלה עליו, והיה רועה, ננער הראם ועמד, והיה דוד רכב על קרניו, והיה גבוה עד השמים, באותה שעה אמר דוד רבונו של עולם אם אתה מורידני מן הראם הזה, אני בונה לך היכל של מאה אמה, כקרני ראם, יש אומרים לארכו מדדו, ויש אומרים לעיגולו מדדו, ומנין ששילם לו נדרו, שנאמר ויבן כמו (ראמים) [רמים] מקדשו (תהלים עח סט), מה עשה לו הקדוש ברוך הוא, זימן לו אריה אחד, וכיון שראה הראם את האריה, נתיירא ממנו, ורבץ בפני האריה, לפי שהאריה מלך על כל החיות והבהמות, כיון שראה דוד את האריה נתיירא הימנו, זימן הקדוש ברוך הוא צבי, קפץ האריה אחריו, ודוד ירד והלך לו, לכך נאמר הושיעני מפי אריה כשם שעניתני מקרני ראמים.

To summarize, David was shepherding, got onto a re'em thinking it was a mountain, then the re'em got up and David pledged that if God would save him, he would build Him a Temple. God sent a lion, and the re'em crouched in front of it. Then God sent a gazelle, and the lion pursued it, allowing David to dismount and leave.

Comment: @EzraHoerster If you like an answer you should consider upvoting it.

Comment: @EzraHoerster You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It appears in Midrash Shocher Tov 102 (also know as Midrash Tehillim); and Yalkut Shimoni 2:688. It is based on the verse in Tehillim 22:22.