# Types of Magic according to Judaism

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, midrash, sorcery-magic-kishuf

The Jewish sources speak in many places about magic e.g [shemot 7:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.7.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [7:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.7.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) & [Vayikra 19:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) etc.

Are there different types? if so what are they?

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 types of magic with which one incurs a being from the upper realm  to fulfil ones wish by creating something/bringing something unavailable, which are both mentioned in the Torah which the necromancers of Egypt used in Sanhedrin 67b:

> - ב**לטיהם** אלו מעשה שדים - "Lot" is the work of a [*sheid*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100977/animal-raim-of-the-midrash/101006#101006) (demon) which one incurs to fulfill (in exchange for a hefty price) [This is forbidden](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%98_%D7%98%D7%96) but not punishable by death.

- ב**להטיהם** אלו מעשה כשפים פירש"י מעשה כשפים ע"י מלאכי חבלה הם נעשים - "Lahat" is incurring work of fire Angels (translation based on Sanhedrin 106b) this is known as *Kishuf* i.e. this is [forbidden punishable by death](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9A_(%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A1_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%98)/%D7%A1%D7%91)

The Gemora explains that a *Sheid* is more accurate than Malachei Chabala and will bring exactly what one wants: אמר אביי דקפיד אמנא שד דלא קפיד אמנא כשפים

There are other categories of magic/superstition which are forbidden:
[**ניחוש**](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%98_%D7%92) - This means superstition on something that has happened in the past e.g. his bread fell from his mouth so he thinks this means that he cannot travel etc. (there is a *Machlokes* on a superstition in the future is permitted like Eliezer and Rivka) *chayav lav*
[**מעונן**](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%98_%D7%98%D7%95) - Making an illusion that people do not understand how it happened  *chayav lav*
[**חובר חבר**](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%98_%D7%94) - whispering spells to cause snakes and other animals to gather round him   *chayav lav*
[**דורש אל מתים**](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%98_%D7%99%D7%92) - Sleeping in the cemetery in order for a *Ruach Tumah* to take hold of him.  *chayav lav*
[**קוסם קסמים**](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95_%D7%9C%D7%90) - Divination through various methods including hitting sticks on the floor and shouting, and watching the effects to divine the future
[**אוב**](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9A_(%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A1_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%98)/%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%94) - Burning incense in order to make him speak the words of the dead through his armpit.  *chayav misah*
[**ידעוני**](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9A_(%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A1_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%98)/%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%95) - Put a certain bird called "Yadua"'s bone in his mouth this makes him speak without control. *chayav Misah*

Comment: So how does one do these things?

Answer (score 1):

[Devarim 18:10-11](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.18.10-11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) lists the following species of magic:

> There shall not be found among you . . . a soothsayer, a diviner of [auspicious] times, one who interprets omens, or a sorcerer,   or a charmer, a pithom sorcerer, a yido'a sorcerer, or a necromancer. (R' A. J. Rosenberg's Judaica Press translation).

See Rashi for a definition of all these at chabad.org (enter Tanakh in Search).

Comment: In short, magic dose not exist. It has never been proven and therefore it is mere fabrication of the wild imagination. Thus, your question is irrelevant when it comes to Judaism. Maimonides rejected the notion of magic as nonsensical. Ibn Ezra also rejects the existence of magic. For example, Ezra says that the reason G-d forbid us communicating with the dead is not because there is a way to do it, rather because its impossible. G-d desires that we use reason and His Torah when discerning Truths.

Comment: @TurkHill There are many episodes throughout Jewish folklore of the deceased appearing in dreams to saintly individuals (throughout history, up to and including the present). That is a form of communication with the dead. Do you deny the veracity of every such occurrence? I don't think there is a compelling basis to do so even from a rationalist perspective such as the Rambam's.

Comment: @user9806 you will admit that the definition of Truth is what we can experience and no-one has ever experienced conversing with the dead because it's impossible to contact them as that is the definition of being dead. In his commentary to Leviticus, 19:31, Ibn Ezra says: "Those with empty brains say 'Were it not that fortune tellers and magicians were true, The Torah would not prohibit them. ' But I (Ibn Ezra) say just the opposite of their words, Because the Torah doesn't prohibit that which is true, But it prohibits that which is false. And the proof is the prohibition on idols and statues."

Comment: @user9806 This is precisely the reason G-d forbids it. An example here is King Saul who believed he spoke to Prophet Samuel, who foretold his impending death in his next activity, war. But in fact, it was only his imagination. He was desperate to conquer which thrilled his emotions to the point where he would latch onto anything ridiculous. He mistook a daydream of Samuel for a title of absolute authority, rendering his vision a fact, which has become so prevalent in many religious circles today. My final example is Rambam who said angels only appeared in visions or in dreams and not folklore.

Comment: @TurkHill Are you claiming that the deceased can not appear in dreams to the living? You say yourself that "Rambam said angels only appeared in visions or in dreams". So if angels can appear in dreams, why not the dead?

Comment: @user9806 As one cannot know a person's thoughts while alive, one cannot equally know their thoughts once deceased. There is no validation for superstitions such as necromancy. All claims are baseless and are a violation of the Torah. Example here is Saul. He did not really speak to Samuel but only his imagination.

Comment: @TurkHill : I'm not talking about necromancy. I'm talking about _dreams_. So even those (like the Rambam) who say necromancy is just a trick, might not say the same about deceased appearing to one in a dream. Which is also a form of communication.

Comment: @user9806 Like Sigmund Freud said, our dreams merely reflect the events of the day. Ex is Talmud, Berachot 56a. There, R. Nahmani said “a man is shown in a dream only what is suggested by his own thoughts.” For ex, one never sees an elephant going through the eye of a needle. Another is the Roman Emperor who asked R. Joshua to predict his dream. The rabbi gave him a clear answer and after contemplating it all day, he dreamt the dream. Similarly, Solomon must have been thinking of his new reign which influenced the content of his dream.

Comment: @user9806 Others includes Jacob, Genesis 28:10-17, and of Esau 32:25-30, Joseph 37:5-10, Pharaoh’s servants 40:5, and Pharaoh’s dreams 41:1-7. The Talmud says dreams are the products of recent experiences. R. Johanan said all dreams have some nonsense. They are other interpretations but the above reflects the majority of talmudic view. There is no source which claim that the dead lift our prayers to heaven. We should rely only on G-d and not “unseen” forces as there is no proof. There is no evidence to suggest one can speak with the dead. It’s impossible and thus a violation to the Torah.

Answer (score -9):

Magic dose not exist. It has never been proven.[1] Maimonides rejected the notion of magic as nonsensical. Ibn Ezra also rejects the existence of magic. For example, Ezra says that the reason G-d forbids us from communicating with the dead is not that there is a way to do it, rather because it's impossible to do so. G-d desires that we use reason and His Torah when discerning Truths.

[1] Although other commentators feel that it does exist.

Comment: We don't know what happened during the prophetic times. It's not too much of a far-stretch if you read through the Bible.

Comment: @Anonymous, we also don’t know what happened in 2nd Temple times. It's not too much of a far-stretch if you read the New Testament. Obviously, Jesus rising from the dead is an impossibility and is a breach to natural law. Maimonides says magic does not exist. It has never been proven. Why imagine a reason, when reason offers an explanation.

Comment: I really don't care about Jc. The people who worship a Jew and claim he is god are responsible for their own actions. But I firmly believe that the limitations of what we call now 'physical laws' were broken during the prophetic times (think of Moses, Avraham) and will be once again broken during Messianic times.

Comment: @Anonymous, just as “physical law” has never been broken in prophetic times, similarly, natural law will not be breached in Messianic times. Study Maimonides. Example here is Joshua. Gersonides (Ralbag) said that the sun never stood still for Joshua. It was metaphor.

Comment: I won't argue with you and just let you be with your opinion.

Comment: Not my opinion. A fact. I’m a rationalist.

Comment: Rambam and Ibn Ezra are only some of many. There are dozens on the opposite side of the argument, who say magic does exist. Does it not strike you as disingenuous to not at least label it a contested subject, rather than declaring it outright "nonsense" by only quoting one side of a very large debate?

Comment: @Yehuda Did the Rambam say that magic was not nonsense and that it could exist because others say it does?

Comment: Forgive me, but... If you are on the level of the Rambam, you don't need to quote him and you can declare magic nonsense yourself; if you are not, then you should quote both sides of a debate amongst individuals greater than any of us. Not doing so is intellectually dishonest.

Comment: @Yehuda Must we also quote the Hindus who think they are many gods because the Indian sages were greater than us!? If your certain about something, is it necessary to quote the other side? Sure, we can but it's not necessary. Would you agree?

Comment: If you are having a conversation comparing Indian and Jewish beliefs, yes. You are discussing mainstream Jewish beliefs, so Indian sages are irrelevant. However, other Jewish sages are not. To not quote other Jewish sages suggests that other Jewish sages are irrelevant, and to do so simply because you like the way the Rambam sounds because "you are a rationalist" is arrogant and self-serving, rather than an honest discussion. To state unequivocally that "magic does not exist" is not an honest or accurate representation of the Jewish debate; only that your opinion is that the Rambam is correct.

Comment: @Yehuda the Sages always argued on each other in their convictions, as there cannot be two true views on a single point. Besides, Rambam's view should be equally acceptable, and self-contradictory? This makes no sense. Rambam taught what he understood was true (ie that magic does not exist), even if others disagreed. Do you feel Rambam should explain other opinions, even if he disagreed with them?

Comment: The Rambam is not the only view to the exclusion of all others. To present the Rambam's view to the exclusion of all others when the question is not exclusively about the Rambam's view is intellectually dishonest because it suggests that the Rambam's view is the only view.

Comment: @Yehuda I added a brief footnote saying that other commentators felt that magic exists. Although I am convinced that the Rambam is right on this point.